# How do I link to backend db without using mapped drive letter?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a FrontEnd and BackEnd database.
FrontEnd is on my pc
BackEnd is on \100.10.5.160\Application Database...my BackEnd file
I then mapped network drive a location for my BackEnd (z:).

Problem is, I've installed the FrontEnd on another user's pc which don't have the same map network drive letter (z:).
Also I intend to install the FrontEnd on another 3 users pcs...

Is there anyway to Programmatically link the BackEnd using a (connection string) like that in vb.net.
I don't like to visit every user to map network drive a letter(z:) ... and so on.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: IF the "Front end" is using link tables to the "backend" then instead of referncing `Z:` you could use the format: `\\100.10.5.160\SomeDir\SomeDataBase.mdb` instead (I believe)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, be it you using custom code, or the built in linked table manager?

Just ensure that when you  link,you use your unc path name, and not the drive path letter.

Now, when you deploy, their drive mapping will not matter. So, use your UNC path name when using the linked table manager, and drive mapping will not matter. In fact, this is a good reason to thus always link the tables using UNC path names as opposed to a mapped drive letter that can often even just change if  a user plugs in a USB jump drive.

Comment: you mean that way,\\100.10.5.160\ApplicationDatabase\myBackEndFile

Comment: Correct, using the above with the linked table  manager, or your custom re-link code will thus work regardless of their drive mapping. As a general rule, if you have security rights with a mapped drive, then you have the same rights with a UNC path name such as your example.